# How to customise Floating Action Button to have different look and feel for enabled and disabled FAB state in Android?

Tags: android, styles, floating-action-button

There is no difference in appearance when FAB is disabled or enabled. How can I achieve a different look and feel for enabled and disabled FAB  via xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to have different look and feel for FAB. The steps I took are -

1) Created a drawable custom_fab.xml at /res/drawable with following content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_disabled"
        android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_enabled"
        android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

This is to have different image for enabled and disabled state.

2) Created a color selector custom_fab_color.xml at /res/color with following content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorFabDisabled" 
        android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorFabEnabled" android:state_enabled="true" /> 
</selector>
```

This is to have different background color for enabled and disabled state of FAB.

3) Added desired color for enabled and disabled state in res/values/colors.xml

```
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="colorFabEnabled">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="colorFabDisabled">#6DABF9</color>>
</resources>
```

4) Updated xml file where FAB is defined. Pointed the src and backgroundTint to the new drawable and color selector.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        ...

        android:backgroundTint="@color/custom_fab_color"
        android:src="@drawable/custom_fab" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the icon when the button is enabled/disabled? For example, if your FAB has an image of a "plus", change this to a red "plus" when disabled and green when enabled.

To do this, you will need to keep track of the state of the FAB.

```
private var fabEnabled = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...

fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    if (fabEnabled) {
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_green_plus)
    } else {
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_plus)
    }
}
```

Change fabEnabled as you wish, such as via another button.

Note this answer is in Koltin. Please tell me if you would rather it in java.

Comment: Can we achieve this via xml?

Comment: You could with Data Binding and Livedata. With Data Binding, in the XML, you can observe a variable such as fabEnabled in MainActivity. If this variable is declared with LiveData, whenever the variable is changed from true to false or false to true, the XML essentially gets redrawn so would update to what you want, such as a different icon.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was able to solve the problem using selector. I have posted the answer.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found a solution in the end which works for you.